# JQuery Mouseover for LI and children

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**UPDATE: I'm an idiot. Forgot the delegate function. Posted my solution below.**

Hey,

Working on a slide script. There is a set of rotating divs and associated LI elements. When the mouse comes over an LI element I'd like to jump directly to that div.

My LI Looks like this:

```
 <li id="infoBox_1" class="infoDefault">
<br>
<h3>Header</h3>
<p>Header</p>
</li>
```

The javascript is this:

```
$('.infoDefault').mouseover(function() {
    alert($(this).id);
    clearInterval(intervalFunc);
});
$('.infoDefault').mouseout(function() {
    startInterval();
});
```

My problem is, the script doesn't seem to be working right. The mouseover function doesn't seem to be recognized at all. Immediately the itnerval is restarted. I am guessing it is because the mouseover function can't catch the children elements iwthin the LI (I.e. the H2 and P tag). But not sure. Can anoyne help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind found the answer. Need to use the delegate function

```
$("#slideList").delegate("li", "hover", function () {
    alert('test');
    clearInterval(funcInterval);

}, function () {
    startInterval();
});
```